# Import C dll in C# , how to convert short** type

Tags: c#, dll, import, pinvoke

I want to import a dll in C# which is coded in C language. The following is the formate of the function I want to call.

```
/*
*ReadAnswer
*@param objectID         The answer object ID
*@param answerBuf        The answer buffer.This buffer is automatically allocated by 
                         the function. 
                         It is automatically recycled with each call. A call to this 
                         function with an empty answer or a new request will 
                         automatically free the allocated buffer.
*@param answerBufferSize The answer buffer size.This function return the size of the 
                         allocated buffer in this parameter.

*@return 0 if error occurs
        1 if success
*/

int ReadAnswer(unsigned short *objectID, 
               unsigned short **answerBuf, unsighed short *answerBufferSize )
```

Please help me with it. I'm stucked by this function. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The C side-of-things is usually not enough to be sure, but after reading the comment, it should be something like this:

```
[DllImport("my.dll")]
private extern static int ReadAnswer(ref ushort objectID, out IntPtr answerBuf, out ushort answerBufferSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

The function should be declared like this:

```
[DllImport(dllname)]
private extern static int ReadAnswer(
    out ushort objectID,
    out IntPtr answerBuf,  
    out ushort answerBufferSize
);
```

Call it like this:

```
ushort objectID, answerBufSize;
IntPtr answerBufPtr;
int retval = ReadAnswer(out objectID, out answerBufPtr,
    out answerBufSize);
if (retval == 0)
    // handle error
ushort[] answerBuf = new ushort[answerBufSize/2];
Marshal.Copy(answerBufPtr, (Int16[])answerBuf, 0, answerBuf.Length);
```

My assumption is that `answerBufSize` is the size in bytes.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply, it does works!! However, my next question is: 1) (Int16[])answerBuf makes error.The error says:cannot convert ushort[] to short[];  2) So I just make the answerBuf to be "short" type. Then  I get "12871", "13104","13636"....,  in answerBuf after Marshal.Copy function.And the result is supposed to be "G203D525",not "12871". What's wrong with it?

Comment: How can G203D525 be an array of unsigned short? As for the other error, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17746580/how-can-i-pass-in-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-of-a-uint16-array-to-a-marshalled-funct

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no *unsigned* keyword in C#, use *ushort*.

Second, in order to declare pointers you need to write *** after the type, example: `ushort*`.

And finally to import dlls which are written in C, use this:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport(requiredDll)]
extern static int ReadAnswer(ushort* objectID, ushort** answerBuf, out ushort* answerBufferSize);
```

Also, since the function put the buffer size in *answerBufferSize*, this parameter requires *out*.