# RCW does not convert integer when passing from .Net to COM

Tags: .net, com, interop, marshalling, unmanaged

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe(v=vs.110).aspx), regarding the conversion of types done by the RCW between .Net client to unmanaged objects, it is written:

> ...Other types require no conversion. For instance, a standard wrapper will always pass a 4-byte integer between managed and unmanaged code without converting the type.

AFAIK,

- Int32 (.Net type) represents a 32-bit signed integer.
- integer (VBA) represents a 16-bit signed

So if an Int32 is passed as parameter from a .Net to a VBA method and no conversion is done by the RCW so how the parameter is passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's important is how the conversion is defined between the two worlds (unmanaged vs managed) in the native or managed code side.

If conversion is defined using a COM / Automation Type Library (in DLL or TLB for example), then it will be declared as the corresponding type automatically, especially for very well known types such as the unsigned 16-bit integer type.

So a VBA 16-bit type will be declared as the equivalent (if it's a standard well-known type) .NET 16-byte. For example, VBA `integer` will be declared as .NET's `Int16` (like the `short` keyword in C#).

If conversion is defined manually, for example using .NET `interface` with COM annotations, then it's the developer's task to ensure the declaration is consistent for both sides (or problems/bugs/crashes may happen).

I suggest two links in the official doc about this: [Default Marshaling Behavior](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zah6xy75.aspx) and [Blittable and Non-Blittable Types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7.aspx) to determine what can be considered as standard or well-known types.

Comment: Thanks @Simon Mourier for the explanation. If I understand you right, it is programmer responsibility to pass as parameter a Int16 to a VBA method for integer?

Comment: It depends on how you define the interface method, but if it's done manually, then yes, like what's done in that question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25134560/import-c-dll-in-c-sharp-how-to-convert-short-type (although it's not COM it's the same idea)

Comment: Thank you for clarification